# workerRequest C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I'm converting some C# code into VB.Net and was stuck on second half of this line:

HttpWorkerRequest workerRequest = (HttpWorkerRequest)provider.GetService(typeof(Http WorkerRequest));

What would this code be in VB.NET?

I have the easy part:

Dim workerRequest As HttpWorkerRequest =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Dim workerRequest As HttpWorkerRequest = DirectCast(provider.GetService(GetType(HttpWorkerRequest), HttpWorkerRequest)
```

Comment: You where missing a close parenthesis:
Dim workerRequest As HttpWorkerRequest = DirectCast(provider.GetService(GetType(HttpWorkerRequest)), HttpWorkerRequest)

Comment: Cheers for that, totally missed it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this:

```
Dim workerRequest As HttpWorkerRequest = CType(provider.GetService(GetType(HttpWorkerRequest)), HttpWorkerRequest)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, the error is where I got stuck:
GetType(Http WorkerRequest))

Comment: There was an extra space that had been sneaking in there; fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The other code on here is right so i wont repeat, but you may find this very useful:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: Although I'm providing a complete line, the site gives the followign error when I try the code:
Statement fragment: please enter a complete statement.

Comment: Hmmm - ive never had that - try pasting in the entire method?